# Cannot understand why program crashes after a couple iterations of while loop?

Tags: c, text-files

I am writing the following program to parse the text file (attached) but it keeps crashing after couple of iterations of while loop or it seems that the buffer storing file contents is corrupted somehow?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char * pick_question(char *, char, int);
char * print_answer(char *, char, int);
int no_of_questions(char*, char);
void clear();
int debug = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    system("cmd /c chcp 1252");
//    system("cmd /c chcp 65001");

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        perror("Please enter a filename!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        debug = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!file)
    {
        perror("Unable to read file!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (debug == 1)
        {
            printf("File opened successfully\n");
        }
    }

    static char *buffer;
    int fileSz;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSz = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = (char*) malloc((fileSz + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (!buffer)
    {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer!");
        exit(0);
    }

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fileSz, file);

    while (1)
    {
        time_t t;
        srand((unsigned) time(&t));
        int sub = rand() % 5 + 1;
        char del;
        switch (sub)
        {
        case 1:
            del = 'A';
            break;
        case 2:
            del = 'B';
            break;
        case 3:
            del = 'C';
            break;
        case 4:
            del = 'D';
            break;
        case 5:
            del = 'E';
        }

        int nrOfQues = no_of_questions(buffer, del);
        if (nrOfQues == 0)
        {
            perror("main(): no_of_questions() returned 0. Unsupported text structure in file or incorrect file encoding!");
            fclose(file);
            exit(0);
        }
        int qNo = rand() % nrOfQues + 1;
        char *ques = pick_question(buffer, del, qNo);
        if (ques)
        {
            printf("\n\n");
            puts(ques);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            perror("main(): pick_question() returned NULL. Unsupported text structure in file!");
            fclose(file);
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Do you want to see the answer(y/n)?");
        char ans, repeat;
        scanf("%c", &ans);
        if ( ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
        {
            char *ans = print_answer(buffer, del, qNo);
            if (ans)
            {
                printf("\n\n");
                puts(ans);
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\n");
                perror("main(): print_answer() returned NULL. Unsupported text structure in file!");
                fclose(file);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        printf("Do you want to try more questions (y/n)?");
        clear();
        scanf("%c", &repeat);
        if (repeat == 'N' || repeat == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
        clear();
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("********  Thank you for using TULE Master! ********");
    printf("\n\n");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

char * pick_question(char * buffer, char sub, int qNo)
{
    char tmpBuff[20];
    char tmpBuff2[20];
    const char * searchStr = "FRÅGA";
    const char * searchStr2 = "A 1 SVAR:";
    const char * searchStr3 = "*****************************************";
    char *pStr, *currPos, *nStr, *tmpStr, *tmpStr2;
    currPos = buffer;

    int count = snprintf(tmpBuff, 20, "FRÅGA %c %d", sub, qNo);

    if (count >= 0 || count < 20)
    {
        if (debug)
        {
            printf("tmpBuff is %s\n", tmpBuff);
        }
        currPos = strstr(currPos, tmpBuff);
        if (currPos)
        {
            pStr = currPos;
            nStr = currPos + 1;
            nStr = strstr(nStr, searchStr);
            if (!nStr)
            {
                nStr = currPos;
                nStr = strstr(nStr, searchStr2);
                if (!nStr)
                {
                    printf("pick_qestion(): nStr is NULL. Unsupported "
                           "text structure");
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
            // Check if it is a scenario based question
            count = snprintf(tmpBuff2, 20, "FRÅGA %c %d", sub, qNo-1);
            if (count >= 0 || count < 20)
            {
                tmpStr = strstr(buffer, tmpBuff2);
                tmpStr2 = strstr(tmpStr, searchStr3);
                if (tmpStr < tmpStr2 && tmpStr2 < pStr)
                {
                    pStr = tmpStr2;
                }
            }
            int qLen = nStr - pStr;
            char *ques = malloc(sizeof(char) * (qLen+1));
            snprintf(ques,qLen,"%s", pStr);
            return ques;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("pick_qestion(): string \"FRÅGA\" not found in file!");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    printf("pick_qestion(): snprintf was not successful!");
    return NULL;
}

char * print_answer(char * buffer, char sub, int qNo)
{
    char tmpBuff[20];
    char *pStr, *currPos, *nStr;

    int count = snprintf(tmpBuff, 20, "%c %d SVAR:", sub, qNo);

    if (count >= 0 || count < 20)
    {
        currPos = strstr(buffer, tmpBuff);
        if (!currPos)
        {
            printf("print_answer(): string \"SVAR\" not found in file!");
        }
        pStr = currPos;
        nStr = currPos + 1;
        char tmpBuff2[20];
        int count = snprintf(tmpBuff2, 20, "%c %d SVAR:", sub, qNo+1);
        if (count < 0 || count >= 20)
        {
            printf("print_answer(): snprint was not successful!");
            return NULL;
        }
        nStr = strstr(nStr, tmpBuff2);
        if (!nStr)
        {
            nStr = buffer + strlen(buffer);
        }
        int ansLen = nStr - pStr;
        char *ans = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ansLen+1));
        snprintf(ans, ansLen, "%s", pStr);
        return ans;
    }
    printf("print_answer(): snprint was not successful!");
    return NULL;
}

int no_of_questions(char *buffer, char sub)
{
    char tmpBuff[20];
    char *currPos, *pStr;

    int count = snprintf(tmpBuff, 20, "FRÅGA %c", sub);

    if (count >= 0 || count < 20)
    {
        if (debug)
        {
            printf("tmpBuff is %s\n", tmpBuff);
        }
        currPos = strstr(buffer, tmpBuff);
        while (currPos != NULL)
        {
            pStr = currPos;
            currPos = currPos + 1;
            currPos = strstr(currPos, tmpBuff);
        }
        if (pStr != buffer)
        {
            pStr += 9;
            char tmpBuff2[20];
            memcpy(tmpBuff2, pStr, 2);
            if (debug)
            {
                printf("No. of questions for %c DEL is are %d\n", sub,
                       atoi(tmpBuff2));
            }
            return atoi(tmpBuff2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
void clear()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
}
```

This is the file that is given as input to the program:
[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bVHbWHyU_rcHJDN3RlYkJxYUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: probably unrelated, but you should only seed the `rand` function once. Move your `srand` call before the `while(1)` loop

Comment: Which while loop? There are 3 while loops in your sample

Comment: ... last time I checked, `fread()` didn't zero-terminate it's target buffer. And since `buffer` points to `malloc()`d memory, it is not zero-filled. Consequently, `buffer` isn't a C-style string (with ''\0'' at the end), yet you call `strstr()` on it. Unless your file contains the terminator, this won't work.

Comment: @hellyale ... the "while(1)" loop

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code in that loop?

Comment: I added null termination to buffer like:

    int buffSz = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fileSz, file);
    buffer[buffSz] = '\0';

But still after several iterations it crashes :)

Any ideas?

Comment: @KenWhite The debugger runs file .... I kept on running the prgoram with the debugger and it also closed after several iterations with the following printout:

"main(): no_of_questions() returned 0. Unsupported text structure in file or incorrect file encoding!"

This mean that the buffer (storing file contents) changed somehow? It should not return since no_of_questions() method searches for "FRÅGA x" where x is randomly chosen to be between A and E.

Comment: Sorry, no. The debugger does not *run fine*. Set a breakpoint at the first line following the `while`. Run to that breakpoint, and then single-step through the code, keeping track of which iteration of the loop you're on. When the error occurs, you'll know exactly where it happened and which time through the loop it was triggered. You can then determine exactly which part of the file is being read, examine variables to see if they contain what they should, etc.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you as I stated that the debugger prints the error:

"main(): no_of_questions() returned 0. Unsupported text structure in file or incorrect file encoding!"

But that means that buffer is corrupted somehow?

Comment: And sometimes I get this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3bVHbWHyU_rMGlvbHhlNTRhS28